# magento 2.2.2 : After Adding new theme product image is not displaying on product page

Tags: jquery, magento2.2.2, theme-overriding

I have added a new theme in **Magento 2.2.2**, everything works fine except **product image**. Product image display in listing page but not display in product view page when product have only one image when I add another image then it displays in product view page.

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you check log files?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it should not happen when you add new theme.

However you can run command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: I have already try this not working please give new solution if u have.